# Windows 10 Outlook: Updating this folder takes a long time

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook

My Windows 10 Outlook is taking a long time to "Updating this folder". Sometimes taking 5-10 min, (my internet is fine)
I have tried

1. Recreating my User Profile
2. Deleted my user inbox and sent messages archive.

Are there any other suggestions to recommend?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this a problem that has only recently occurred? If so, what specific operations did you do before this problem occurred?

Did you recreate your profile via Control Panel > Mail > Show profile? If not, please try.

What's the type of your account? Exchang, IMAP or POP?

With outlook open, hold down ctrl and right click the outlook icon in the system tray, a new menu will appear > Connection status and test email autoconfiguration, Check both to see if any obvious errors show up

To check whther this is the issue with your email account, it is also suggested to configure another email account on your Outlook and see if the issue persists.